# How do I merge new features from a source repo locally without overriding my modifications?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I cloned a Jekyll theme from a Github repository locally onto my Windows 10 PC.

Since I wanted to personalize this theme, I made my own modifications to the code files.

I visited the original repository belonging to the author of this Jekyll theme and he made an update that I could benefit from.

I'm not sure how to merge this feature update to my local repo without overriding the changes I already made to the code.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a `git pull`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

`git pull` is sort of just a `git fetch` and then a `git merge`. Merging in git will not overwrite your changes with the new changes- it will try to consolidate them. When it cannot consolidate the changes you get what's called a merge conflict. Here is a lengthy discussion on merge conflicts: [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Edit: To be safe, make sure you've committed your changes before you attempt this.